# Use sed to delete all lines starting with pattern b after line with pattern a

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, string-matching

Given a file like:

```
first line
second line DELETE ME
  - third line
  - fourth line
fifth line
sixth line DELETE ME
seventh line
  - eighth line
```

as well as pattern **a** (`DELETE ME`) and pattern **b** (`[[:blank:]]*-`), I would like to retain only

```
first line
fifth line
seventh line
  - eighth line
```

or in other words, I'd like to delete each line containing pattern **a** as well as all *directly following* lines starting with pattern **b**.

So far I've only managed to fulfill some but not all of my requirements:

```sh
sed '/DELETE ME/{N;s/^[[:blank:]]*-//;d;}'
```

This should delete all lines containing **a** as well as one consecutive line containing **b**.

Comment: Are you committed to sed, or will other tools be acceptable?

Comment: Is this a yaml file?

Comment: `sed '/DELETE ME/{:a;N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*-.*//;ta;!P;D}' file`

Comment: My ultimate goal is this: I have a gitlab-ci template repository consisting of many gitlab-ci yaml files, using (possibly nested) includes. Now I want to create a gitlab-ci file for that repository, checking all files included for validity against the [included CI lint tool](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html) ([API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html). I found [this solution](https://gitlab.lrz.de/snippets/234) for slightly less generic cases, but want to adapt it to my use case. --- @WiktorStribiżew that seems to work, would you mind adding explanation and submitting as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed '/DELETE ME/{:a;N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*-.*//;ta;!P;D}' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/K82PPe):

```
s='first line
second line DELETE ME
  - third line
  - fourth line
fifth line
sixth line DELETE ME
seventh line
  - eighth line'
sed '/DELETE ME/{:a;N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*-.*//;ta;!P;D}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
first line
fifth line
seventh line
  - eighth line
```

**Details**

- `/DELETE ME/` - finds all lines that contain `DELETE ME` string
- `{:a;N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*-.*//;ta;!P;D}` - if the line matching `DELETE ME` is found, this block is entered:

  - `:a` - an `a` label marks the current position
  - `N` - reads the next line with `\n` at the start into the pattern space
  - `s/\n[[:blank:]]*-.*//` - finds and removes the newline, 0+ blank chars, `-` and the rest of the string
  - `ta` - if the substitution occurred, `sed` goes to the position marked with `a`
  - `!P` - otherwise, prints the pattern space content until the first newline (i.e. prints the first line)
  - `D` - deletes the pattern space content until the first new line, i.e. deletes the first line inside pattern space, and restarts cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

Answer (score 0):

Though yaml files should be parsed by tools which understand them, since OP has used `sed` so I am coming with an `awk` solution here. Could you please try following. Written and tested in link https://ideone.com/WNROOt and tested and written with shown samples only.

```
awk '
!/^ +/{
  foundDel=""
}
/DELETE ME/{
  foundDel=1
  next
}
foundDel && /^ +/{
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

NOTE: In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/DELETE ME/{:a;n;/^\s*-/ba};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by setting the option `-n`.

On encountering a line containing `DELETE ME`, form a loop that fetches the next line and if that line begins with some spaces followed by a `-`, repeat the loop.

Otherwise, print all other line.

Comment: This yields `sed: unterminated {` in my setting.

Comment: Try `'/DELETE ME/{:a;n;/^\s*-/ba;};p'`